# Cannot import file because of file name

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, import

I need to import a python file from another folder. To do that I am using the following lines of code

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/mininet/Sandbox/mapper')
from parser import read-dir
```

I get a syntax error because my python file name has a "-" character

```
from parser import read-dir
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is there any way to get around it?

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path

Comment: Can you rename the file? `read-dir` isn't a valid variable name (it's a subtraction expression), but `read_dir` would be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your file has `-` character in file name. Instead of `import`, use [`__import__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#__import__) or [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html).

For example, I have a script called `h-e-l-l-o.py`:

```
>>> import h-e-l-l-o
  File "<input>", line 1
    import h-e-l-l-o
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax


>>> import importlib
>>> importlib.import_module('h-e-l-l-o')
<module 'h-e-l-l-o' from '/home/kevin/h-e-l-l-o.py'>


>>> __import__('h-e-l-l-o')
<module 'h-e-l-l-o' from '/home/kevin/h-e-l-l-o.py'>
>>>
```